# Postgres polygon array - правильный формат insert-а

Tags: postgresql, polygon

У меня есть таблица со столбцом типа polygon[] . insert в поля типа polygon делаю так:

```
INSERT INTO TABLES test (p_field) VALUES ('((0,0),(1,0),(1,1), (0,0))');
```

Успешно. Но в поля типа polygon [] не могу понять, в каком формате подавать данные. Пробовала так:

> '{( (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0) ), ( (0, 0), (5, 0) ,(0, 1) , (0, 0) )}'
>
> '{'( (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0))', '((0, 0), (5, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0) )'}'

... и еще по всякому по-разному, но каждый раз все равно ругается на неправильный формат. Не нашла никакой информации в сети. Может быть кто-то сталкивался и знает, как их правильно скармливать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`polygon[]` - это массив и N элементов типа `polygon`. Поэтому сперва формируете данные формата, [подходящего для `polygon`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#DATATYPE-POLYGON)

Затем формируете массив из них же:

```
INSERT INTO test (p_field) VALUES (array[
  '((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0))',
  '((0, 0), (5, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0))'
]::polygon[]);
```

Либо строковым литералом, в котором согласно формату массивов используются кавычки:

```
INSERT INTO test (p_field) VALUES ('{"((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0))", "((0, 0), (5, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0))"}');
```

---

Пример синтаксиса строкового литерала можно в общем-то попросить показать саму базу:

```
create temp table test (p_field polygon);
INSERT INTO test (p_field) VALUES ('((0,0),(1,0),(1,1), (0,0))');
select array_agg(p_field) from test;
```